# How can I remove white space between divs?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I'm working on my portfolio site, and I have no idea how to get rid of the white space.

Based on the inspect element there is styling to ul.AMSI but it is not used in my styles.css

image is hosted at
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oke33.png

I tried to inspect element, but it doesn't help.

Any hints on this will be much appreciated.

URL : https://portfolio-thomas-2019.herokuapp.com/

---

## update

Thanks again for the support

what I have tried

removing all AMSI Li padding and margin

```
.AMSI li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EC7108;
}
```

commented out margins and paddings in different areas around my issue in hopes of finding the issue but I cannot find it.

I went to the extremes of changing the body background to the hex #EC7108.

Given my experience I don't know of any other angles to approach my issue but ask all the great developers out there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @Thomas McCabe can you share with a JSFiddle example code? We can't help without it...

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the support! As soon as I did that it doesn't seem to take effect : https://i.imgur.com/FzVEoUT.png

Comment: @ChrisLi : What do you mean ? removing it seems do nothing ? I also tried your comment.

Comment: you have a stray <p> tag just below the <ul> element. remove that <p> tag.

Comment: Thank you everyone again for all the support, appreciate everyone's kindness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ul>` element is part of the problem. You should add this style to it

```
.AMSI {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

this by itself does not fix it. However, there is a stray `<p></p>` on the page, just after this `<ul>` element.

You should remove this `<p>` tag (assuming it's empty because you are not using it.)
This `<p>` tag has a margin-bottom of 1rem which is causing the white space

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! I'd up vote to support but I don't have enough cred yet

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the page and it would appear the problem is related to the style associated with the un-ordered list your social media icons are in.

```
.AMSI li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EC7108;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The margin bottom is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is margin-bottom in your ul class="AMSI" you need to set margin-bottom: 0

And you got a p tag below ul class="AMSI" got empty content inside and it got margin-bottom also. Then just remove it too.